# Short time limits for SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and let $X$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t \;, \quad  X_0 = x_0\;.$$

where $\sigma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a Lipschitz continuous function, and $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ is a fixed constant.

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, let $A_\varepsilon$ denote the event

$$\{\underset{0 \leq t \leq \varepsilon}{\text{max}} W_t  \geq 1\} \;, $$

and let $\mathbb P^\varepsilon$ be the probability measure given by

$$\mathbb P^\varepsilon (E) = \frac{\mathbb P(E \cap A_\varepsilon)}{\mathbb P(A_\varepsilon)} \;, $$

for all events $E$.

We denote by $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon}$ the expectation under $\mathbb P^\varepsilon$.

Consider the solution $Y$ to the deterministic ODE

$$dY_t = \sigma(Y_t) \, dt \; , \quad Y_0 = x_0.$$

**Question:** Is it true that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \, \mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon} \big [\underset{0 \leq t \leq \varepsilon}{\sup} |X_t - Y_{t/\varepsilon} | \, \big] = 0?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau = \inf\{ t>0 : W_t = 1 \}$.  The conjecture is **true** and the essence of the proof outlined below appears to be the following peculiar property of the hitting time $\tau$: $$
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} P_{\epsilon}[\tau > \epsilon-\epsilon^{3/2}] = 1 \;. $$
(This can be computed directly using the fact that distribution of $\tau$ is [inverse gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) with parameters $1/2$ and $1/2$.) In order to leverage this property, one must carefully split up $e_t:= X_t - Y_{t/\epsilon}$ as outlined below.

> **Theorem**. It holds that:  $$\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0}  E[ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} |e_t|^2 ] = 0 \;.$$

**Proof**.
The proof shows that for any $T \in [0, \epsilon]$ $$
E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le T} |e_t|^2 ] \le C_1(\epsilon) + C_2 (\epsilon) \int_0^T E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le r \le s} |e_r|^2 ] ds  
$$ where $C_1(\epsilon)$ and $C_2 (\epsilon) $ are non-negative and $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0}  C_1(\epsilon) =0$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} C_2(\epsilon) \epsilon = O(1)$.  By Grönwall's inequality,  $$
E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} |e_t|^2 ] \le C_1(\epsilon) \exp(C_2 (\epsilon) \epsilon) \;,
$$ and then passing to the limit gives the required result.  The remaining details follow.

By Itô's formula, \begin{align*}
& |e_t|^2 = \mathrm{I} +  \mathrm{II} +  \mathrm{III} \quad \text{where} \\
&  \mathrm{I}:= \frac{2}{\epsilon} \int_0^t e_s (\sigma(X_s) - \sigma(Y_{s/\epsilon})) ds \;, \\
&  \mathrm{II}:= \frac{2}{\epsilon} \int_0^t e_s \sigma(X_s) (\epsilon dW_s - ds) \;, \\
&  \mathrm{III}:= \int_0^t \sigma(X_s)^2 ds \;. 
\end{align*}

---

*Estimate for $\mathrm{I}$.*

This term exclusively contributes to $C_2(\epsilon)$.
Since $\sigma$ is $L$-Lipschitz for some $L>0$ $$
I \le \frac{2 L}{\epsilon} \int_0^t |e_s|^2 ds 
$$ and thus $$
\sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} I \le \frac{2 L}{\epsilon} \int_0^{\epsilon} |e_s|^2 ds \le \frac{2 L}{\epsilon} \int_0^{\epsilon} \sup_{0 \le r \le s} |e_r|^2 ds \;.
$$
Thus, $C_2(\epsilon) = 2 L / \epsilon$.

---

*Estimate for $\mathrm{II}$.*

This term contributes to $C_1(\epsilon)$, and here is where we leverage the aforementioned peculiar property of $\tau$.
\begin{align*}
& \lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \mathrm{II} \right| ]  = 
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \mathrm{II} \right| \mathbf{1}_{ \{ \tau > \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} } ] \\
& \quad = 
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} E [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| 2 \int_0^t e_s \sigma(X_s) dW_s \right| ] = 0
\end{align*}
Here we took 3 steps that are explained in detail below.

*In the first step*, we used Cauchy-Schwarz to show that $$
\left( E_{\epsilon} \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} |\mathrm{II}| \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau < \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} } \right)^2 \le \underbrace{E[\sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} |\mathrm{II}|^2 ]}_{\to O(1)} \, \underbrace{P_{\epsilon}[ \tau < \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2}]}_{\to 0} 
$$

*In the second step*, we used a natural splitting and the triangle inequality to write, \begin{align*}
& E_{\epsilon} \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} |\mathrm{II}| \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau > \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} } \le \mathrm{II}_a + \mathrm{II}_b \quad \text{where} \\
& \mathrm{II}_a :=  E_{\epsilon} \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon}  \frac{2}{\epsilon} \left| \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} e_s \sigma(X_s) (\epsilon dW_s - ds) \right| \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau > \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} }\\
& \mathrm{II}_b :=  E_{\epsilon}  \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon}  \frac{2}{\epsilon} \left| \int_{t \wedge \tau}^t e_s \sigma(X_s) (\epsilon dW_s - ds) \right| \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau > \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} }
\;.
\end{align*}
To estimate these terms, there are two cases to consider:

- *Case 1: $t \le \tau$*. Then $\mathrm{II}_b=0$ and $\mathrm{II}_a$ can be written in terms of the piece of the Brownian bridge up to time $t$; and,
- *Case 2: $t > \tau$*.  Then $t>\epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2}$ and hence $\mathrm{II}_b=O(\epsilon^{1/2})$ and again  $\mathrm{II}_a$ can be written in terms of the piece of the Brownian bridge up to time $\tau$.

In other words, conditioned on the event $(\tau < \epsilon)$, the law of $\epsilon W_s - s$ is equal to the law of a standard Brownian bridge.

*In the third and last step*, we used [Doob's martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Further_inequalities), [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), and (standard) a priori bounds on $X_t$ and $Y_{t/\epsilon}$ over $(0,\epsilon)$.  Since the estimate of this term is almost identical to the estimate of $\mathrm{III}$ given below, the details are suppressed.

---

*Estimate for $\mathrm{III}$.*

This term also contributes to $C_1(\epsilon)$.  Noting that $\sigma$ is $L$-Lipschitz, \begin{align*}
E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \mathrm{III} ] &= E_{\epsilon}[ \int_0^{\epsilon}  [ \sigma(X_s)^2 ds ] \\
&\le 2 \epsilon \sigma(0)^2 + 2 L^2 E_{\epsilon}[ \int_0^{\epsilon} |X_s|^2 ds ] \\
&\le 2  \epsilon ( \sigma(0)^2 + L^2 |x_0|^2 ) + 2 L^2 \epsilon \int_0^{\epsilon} \sigma(X_s)^2 ds \\ 
& \quad + 2 L^2 \epsilon \int_0^{\epsilon} X_s \sigma(X_s) dW_s
\end{align*}
and as long as $2 L^2 \epsilon \le 1/2$, it follows that
$$
E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \mathrm{III} ] \le 4  \epsilon ( \sigma(0)^2 + L^2 |x_0|^2 ) + 4 L^2 \epsilon \int_0^{\epsilon} X_s \sigma(X_s) dW_s
$$ The last term in this expression can be treated in a similar way as the last step in the estimate for $\mathrm{II}$, namely [Doob's martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Further_inequalities), Cauchy-Schwarz, [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), and (standard) a priori bounds on $X_t$ over $(0,\epsilon)$.  In particular, \begin{align*}
\left( E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \int_0^t X_s \sigma(X_s) d W_s \right| ] \right)^2 &\le
E \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \int_0^t X_s \sigma(X_s) dW_s \right|^2\\
&\le 4 E \left| \int_0^{\epsilon} X_s \sigma(X_s) dW_s \right|^2 \\
&\le 4 E \int_0^{\epsilon} X_s^2 \sigma(X_s)^2 ds \\
&\le 4 \tilde{C}_2 (1+ x_0^4) e^{\tilde{C}_1 \epsilon} \epsilon
\end{align*}
where in turn we used Cauchy-Schwarz, Doob's martingale inequality with $p=2$, Itô's isometry, and then an a priori bound on the second/fourth moment of $X_t$ over $(0, \epsilon)$.

$\Box$

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I’ll read through this properly today.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but I have several questions about the estimate for $II$. Firstly, how does one derive  $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \mathrm{II} \right| ]  = 
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} E_{\epsilon} [ \sup_{0 \le t \le \epsilon} \left| \mathrm{II} \right| \mathbf{1}_{ \{ \tau > \epsilon - \epsilon^{3/2} \} } ]$ in the first step? I understand that we use the property $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} P_{\epsilon}[\tau > \epsilon-\epsilon^{3/2}] = 1$, but I am not sure how to conclude that the expectation matches in the limit.

Comment: My second question concerns the Brownian bridge - I understand that $W_t - \frac{t}{\epsilon} W_\epsilon$ is a (scaled) Brownian bridge on $[0, \epsilon]$, independent of $W_\epsilon$, and hence conditional on any event involving only $W_\epsilon$, it is still a Brownian bridge. Thus after scaling by $\epsilon$ we get that $\epsilon W_s - s$ is a standard Brownian bridge on $[0, \epsilon]$ conditional on $W_\epsilon = 1$. However, we condition on $\tau < \epsilon$ which involves the path of $W$ before time $\epsilon$, further it is not certain that $W_\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could help me understand these steps.

Comment: Based on your feedback/questions (thanks!), added more detail to the estimate of $\mathrm{II}$.

Comment: Thank you for the added details! It makes sense to me now. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example, take  $dX_t = 2 dB_t$.  By the reflection principle the conditioned process is symmetric around 1, but $Y_1 = 2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reflection principle part?

Comment: I assume you want to reflect after $W$ hits $1$, but wouldn’t that make $X$ symmetric around $2$? I don’t see any contradiction…

Comment: You are conditioning on whether the process has hit the level 1 before time $\epsilon$, but according to the strong markov property, after it hits 1, it is equally likely to go up or down, making the distribution conditioned on having hit 1 symmetric around 1.  This application of the SMP is the reflection principal.  BTW, I would expect conditioned as you have, virtually any process would satisfy $X_{\epsilon} \approx 1$  because I would expect that generally speaking is crosses preponderantly near time $\epsilon$.

Comment: But we condition on $W$ hitting $1$, not $X$. $X$ would hit $2$ at the time $W$ hits $1$.

Comment: my mistake, i did not notice.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for clarifying your reasoning anyway.